# ViewPager for displaying 5 Views at the same time or other options in Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm currently using a ViewPager with a pageWidth of 0.2 to display 5 Views at the same time. This logically requires an offscreen-limit from 7, to have a smooth transition between the views.

In the beginning I used a FragmentStatePagerAdapter but I was worried about the memory-consumption and the performance. This was the reason why I now only use a PagerAdapter to display my views.

What I want (and what I have):

<<-- View | View View View View View | View -->>

Is there any other approach in android to handle this? I thought about using a LinearLayout with a ScrollView but I need to "stick" to the Views after swiping. And I really like the custom-page indicators of the view.

Furthermore: Shall I save the views (of the elements) in my objects or should I recreate them after every call (and yes, I'm removing them in destroyItem) ?

Another question: Was it the right decision to switch from FragmentStatePageAdapter to a PagerAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the document,  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

> Implementation of PagerAdapter that uses a Fragment to manage each page. This class also handles saving and restoring of fragment's state.
>
> This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much less memory associated with each visited page as compared to FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when switching between pages.

Therefore, if you have a lot of pages, using `FragementStatePageAdapter` is better. `FragementStatePageAdapter` is more efficient on memory management.

But if you want cache 2 pages outside screen, no matter `FragmentStatePageAdapter` and `PageAdapter`, you have to cache them by yourself. Use `SimpleOnPageChangeListener` to catch page change event, then do some initialization for next page.

Answer (score 1):

After removing the views from the container in `destroyItem()` keep them in an `ArrayList`. During `instantiateItem()`, first check if you have unused views in your arraylist, if so, use that one. If not, inflate one.

The garbage collector may or may not have collected the view, so you need to do a pre-check before you can use it.